# Gitlab: push to feature branch without having to create merge request

Tags: gitlab

In gitlab, is it possible for someone in the "developer" group to push to a feature branch without having to create merge request?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

can run git push branch
If you have permissions but have permissions, you cannot merge but only create the request
if the branch belongs to you, only the code will be inserted